# Get list of all ipv4 and ipv6 under same hostname

Tags: c++, linux, ipv6, ipv4, hosts

Suppose I have entries in /etc/hosts like:

> 10.10.64.225 HostName1
>
> 10.10.64.226 HostName1
>
> 10.10.64.227 HostName1
>
> FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329 HostName1
>
> 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 HostName1

Now I want a list of all IP's under same host name.

I am using `getaddrinfo` function.

**test.c file:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *list, *curr;
    int arg, errcode;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s HOSTNAME ...\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {

        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
        hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

        errcode = getaddrinfo(argv[arg], NULL, &hints, &list);
        if (errcode) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], gai_strerror(errcode));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        for (curr = list; curr != NULL; curr = curr->ai_next) {
            if (curr->ai_family == AF_INET) {
                char addrbuf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN + 1];
                const char *addr;

                addr = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((struct sockaddr_in *)curr->ai_addr)->sin_addr), addrbuf, sizeof addrbuf);
                if (addr == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                printf("%s: IPv4 = %s\n", argv[arg], addr);

            } else
            if (curr->ai_family == AF_INET6) {
                char addrbuf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN + 1];
                 const char *addr;

                addr = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)curr->ai_addr)->sin6_addr), addrbuf, sizeof addrbuf);
                if (addr == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                printf("%s: IPv6 = %s\n", argv[arg], addr);

            }
        }
        freeaddrinfo(list);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output:**
./test HostName1

ks1: IPv4 = 10.10.64.225

ks1: IPv6 = FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329

The issue in code is, it return only first IPV4 and first IPV6 address.
and I need a list of all IP's under same Host name.

Comment: I'm not sure the `hosts` style resolver is obligated to enumerate all possible addresses like the `bind` (DNS) one is. Have you tried this with a DNS equivalent?

Comment: I have tried with my old DNS which have only IPv4 address and it returns all IPv4. So I am not sure it would work with both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: DNS uses `A` and `AAAA` records to resolve. You may need to ask for both types explicitly.

Comment: It works for me with multiple IP addresses in `/etc/hosts`. I don't think the problem is in your code, but in your operating system configuration.